# Doctrine2 createNativeQuery returns an object with one result when there are more

Tags: doctrine-orm

I have the following Doctrine2 code:

```
$sql = 'SELECT user_name, user_email FROM users';

$rsm = new ResultSetMapping();
$rsm->addEntityResult('Entity\Users', 'u');
$rsm->addFieldResult('u', 'user_name', 'userName');
$rsm->addFieldResult('u', 'user_email', 'userEmail');

$query = $this->em->createNativeQuery($sql, $rsm);
$users = $query->getResult();
```

Which returns an array with 1 item for the first user. However, If I change it to

```
$users = $query->getArrayResult();
```

It returns the full set of users as expected.  Can anyone see what is the problem here?

Thanks!

P.S.
Yes, I know this simple query doesn't require createNativeQuery, but my real query is too complex for QueryBuilder or DQL, and I have simplified it to see whether the problem is with the query. It isn't.

Answer (score 0):

The `ArrayHydrator` (used by `getArrayResult`) checks if your query only has 1 EntityResult mapping, if so it continues to populate the result array even after the identifierMap has been set for that EntityResult alias. The `ObjectHydrator` (used by `getResult`) does not perform that check, for whatever reason, so it stops populating the array after setting the first value.

You can see for yourself by looking at `ArrayHydrator->_isSimpleQuery`